# Element-plus Autocomplete cause the page rerendering

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, vuejs3, element-plus

Good day everyone,I have a question.
I use asp.net core razor page and Vue3 Options API to build the web APP,
now I want to use the el-autocomplete to suggest the user complete the input and the other different input will complete the corresponding data when the autocomplete finish.
But now I find the all page will re-render when I type each characters in autocomplete and when the blur event fires.
How can I fix it?I think I use the Ajax will not cause the page rerendering?

Thank you for help.

Here with the code I tried.

```
.platform-auto-complete {
            pointer-events: none;
            color: #999;
        }
```

```
 <el-autocomplete v-model="OwnerName"
       :fetch-suggestions="querySearch"
       clearable
       @@clear="setBlur()"
       class="inline-input w-50"
       placeholder="Please Input"
     :trigger-on-focus="false"
      :popper-class="noData ? 'platform-auto-complete' : ''"
      @@select="getOwnerId"
     :teleported="false"
      size="large"
     :append-to-body="false">
 </el-autocomplete>
```

```
 async querySearch(queryString, cb) {
                    var _this = this;
                    if (queryString) {
                        _this.OwnerName = queryString;
                        let data = await this.getOwnerList(_this.OwnerName)
                        let ownerList = data
                        //console.log(ownerList)
                        if (ownerList.length == '0') {
                            ownerList.push({
                                id: '-1',
                                value: 'No data'
                            });
                            this.noData = true
                            cb(ownerList);
                            //console.log("A")
                        } else {
                            ownerList = ownerList.map(owner => {
                                return {
                                    id: `${owner}`,
                                    value: `${owner}`
                                }
                            });
                            this.noData = false
                            cb(ownerList)
                            //console.log("B")
                        }
                    }
                },
                async getOwnerList(queryString) {
                    var _this = this;
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('queryString', queryString);
                    let result = await $axiosPost(this.localRouter + "?handler=GetOwnerList", fd);
                    //console.log(result)
                    if (result.result === 'success') {
                        return result.list;
                    } else {
                        return [];
                    }
                },
                setBlur() {                    
                    document.activeElement.blur()
                    //console.log("C")
                },
                async getOwnerId() {
                    var _this = this;
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('owner', this.OwnerName);
                    let result = await $axiosPost(this.localRouter + "?handler=GetOwnerId", fd)
                    //console.log(result)
                    //console.log("D")
                    if (result.ownerId[0] == 'Temp_0001') {
                        this.OwnerId = ''
                    } else {
                        this.OwnerId = result.ownerId[0]
                    }
                },
```